# Plotting a Bode from a Transfer Function on Matlab

Tags: dc-dc-converter, transfer-function, feedback, matlab, bode-plot

I need a bode plot for a transfer function from matlab which I never did before. I tried some examples but failed. How to do this on matlab?
Here is the TF:

[image]

Comment: Make \$s = j\omega\$ and solve.

Comment: Use the function `tf` ([link to documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html)) to build your transfer function, then `bode` ([link to documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/bode.html)) to plot. You don't show those examples that you tried, so people might conclude that you're tying to make them do your job.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming wp0 = C , wz1 = Z1 , wz2 = Z2; wp1 = p1, wp2 = p2

expand the the numerator and denominator as follows
Numerator of TF = C*(((s^2/(z1z2)) +(s(z1+z2)/z1z2) + (1/z1/z2)))
Denominator of TF = (((s^3/(p1*p2)) +(s^2(p1+p2)/p1p2) + (s/p1/p2)))

the code in matlab to implement this is as follows

sys = tf([C*(1/z1z2) C*((z1+z2)/z1z2)) C*(1/z1/z2)],[(1/(p1*p2)) ((p1+p2)/p1p2) (1/p1/p2) 0]);

bode(sys);